Selenium IDE green tick execution tracing lost after following run command test step
After Run command test step, the execution trace green ticks are totally lost and it makes to find failure, only way I can find status is using log in bottom of screen.
Execution shows green tick on top level test, then green ticks show up inside called tests, but after exiting called test gree tick is missing.

Is there any way to get this tracing in all levels of run command calls?
